# Running sum list for prolog?

Tags: prolog

Hello I am trying to do something like this where I am able call to call: 
running_list([1, 4, -5, 5, -2], R)  and the results should be:  R = [1, 5, 0, 5, 3]

I run into a loop which I can't seem to figure out.

```
running_list([], []).
running_list([First], [First]).
running_list([First, Second], Total) :-
   Total is First + Second.
running_list([First, Second|Tail], [First|Total]) :-
   Current is First + Second,
   running([Current|Tail], Total).
```

I would appreciate any help or working solution if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're carrying the sum from the start to the end of the list, you will need to carry the partial sum along as an extra argument. In addition, you're mixing your arguments up a bit. In some cases your second argument is a list, and sometimes it's treated as an integer. That will lead to failure of the predicate.

To start the process, you need to use an auxiliary predicate that uses 3 arguments instead of two. The following starts out with a rule that indicates that the running sum is initially the first element of the list.

```
run([], []).
run([X|T], [X|ST]) :-
    run(T, X, ST).
```

Then we need to do the recursive `run/3` definition:

```
run([], _, []).            % For an empty list, the running sum is irrelevant
run([X|T], S, [S1|ST]) :-  % For a list start with X, the new list has a new running sum (S1)
    S1 #= X + S,           % New running sum (S1) is the current running sum plus X
    run(T, S1, ST).        % recurse on the tails of the lists with the new running sum
```

Notice that I'm using `#=` here instead of `is/2` since it's best when reasoning with integers. For your purposes, you can just as well use `is/2`.

Here are some results:

```
| ?- run([1], L).

L = [1]

yes
| ?- run([1,2], L).

L = [1,3]

yes
| ?- run([1,2,3], L).

L = [1,3,6]

yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Ah an accumulator is what I needed to use and thank you for pointing out that I was mixing up my arguments! I appreciate you for taking the time to write your explanations!